# dropdown in jquery with multi-line and images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which jquery extension do you use to add images to a jquery drop down?

Example
User types in person's name, a drop down list appears with person's profile picture, name and description and company icon. User selects person from drop down list.

```
[PROFILE-PHOTO] FirstName LastName [COMPANY_ICON]
                Description

[PROFILE-PHOTO] FirstName LastName [COMPANY_ICON]
                Description

[PROFILE-PHOTO] FirstName LastName [COMPANY_ICON]
                Description
```

EDIT: dropdown list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the native jQuery UI Autocomplete with some simple modifications to add images.  Not only is it lighter weight than others out there, it's got far more developers behind it and a strong standards group ensuring it won't bloat in the future.

Here's a great example on a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/K5q5U/

Comment: wow, that is what i am after :) thanks alot! how would I insert another image on the right side btw?

Comment: I trying to figure out why the same code in my website doens't show the images